# SQL Server 2012 Case statement cannot update what I need it to update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how to make this formula work for my SQL Server 2012, and it has me completely stumped. In the first `case` statement where I am trying to set the `Dateupdated` column, on the middle line, I have it as

```
WHEN standardunitcost > (averageunitcost + 2.000000) THEN GETDATE()
```

I need to add something extra in there to make sure that the `(Averageunitcost + 2.000000)` is greater than 22. When I try to set it up as `((Averageunitcost + 2.000000) > 22.000000)` it is incompatible.

Can someone explain to me why I cannot do it the way I am currently trying, and how to make this work properly? Also, I'm sorry if this is in the incorrect place, or has been asked before, but I'm not really sure what to search for to solve this!

```
UPDATE [mas_wgd].[dbo].[CI_Item]
SET dateupdated = CASE
                     WHEN StandardUnitCost < AverageUnitCost THEN GETDATE()
                     WHEN standardunitcost > (AverageUnitCost + 2.000000) THEN GETDATE()
                     WHEN StandardUnitCost < 22.000000 THEN GETDATE()
                     ELSE dateupdated
                  END
WHERE ProductLine IN ('A010', 'A020', 'A030', 'A040', 'A050', 'A060', 'A070', 'A080', 'A090', 'A100', 'A110', 'A120', 'A130', 'A130', 'A140', 'A150', 'A200', 'A250', 'A300', 'A350', 'A400', 'A450', 'A500', 'A550', 'A600', 'AGNC', 'C010', 'C020', 'C030', 'C040', 'C050', 'C060', 'C070', 'C080', 'C090', 'C100', 'C110', 'C120', 'C130', 'C130', 'C140', 'C150', 'C200', 'C250', 'C300', 'C350', 'C400', 'C450', 'C500', 'C550', 'C600', 'CGNC')

UPDATE [mas_wgd].[dbo].[CI_Item]
SET Standardunitcost = CASE
                          WHEN (AverageUnitCost between 0.010000 and 22.000000) THEN 22.00000
                          WHEN AverageUnitCost > 22.000000 THEN AverageUnitCost + 2.000000
                          ELSE StandardUnitCost 
                        END
WHERE ProductLine IN ('A010', 'A020', 'A030', 'A040', 'A050', 'A060', 'A070', 'A080', 'A090', 'A100', 'A110', 'A120', 'A130', 'A130', 'A140', 'A150', 'A200', 'A250', 'A300', 'A350', 'A400', 'A450', 'A500', 'A550', 'A600', 'AGNC', 'C010', 'C020', 'C030', 'C040', 'C050', 'C060', 'C070', 'C080', 'C090', 'C100', 'C110', 'C120', 'C130', 'C130', 'C140', 'C150', 'C200', 'C250', 'C300', 'C350', 'C400', 'C450', 'C500', 'C550', 'C600', 'CGNC')
```

Comment: Is it as simple as this? WHEN standardunitcost > averageunitcost + 2 AND Averageunitcost + 2 > 22 then GETDATE()

Comment: btw, unless you are using all the decimal places to implicitly change the datatype that is just a lot of extra typing.

Comment: why is the 2nd update statement there?

Comment: The 2nd update statement is actually set to update the StandardUnitCost. The StandardUnitCost I'm trying to keep at 2 over the Averageunitcost. I just didn't know how to tie in updating the dateupdate field into the same statement that I was updating the standardunitcost field. I'm pretty new to SQL as a whole.

Comment: Then that should be stated as part of the question. Right now it looks to be extraneous.

Comment: Well, its not an issue for me currently. I was just pulling my hair out over that one simple fix. I may make a new question in the future to ask that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, it _can_ be part of this question. Both can be handled in the same UPDATE. I was just trying to work out what the 2nd one is doing and it is also odd because it skips values 22.00001 through 24.00000 (based on the first two conditions).

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to state that the minimum StandardUnitCost is 22. But I once again see the need for a >= marker to include 24. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact syntax that is not working has not been posted, but is implied as being:

```
WHEN standardunitcost > ((Averageunitcost + 2.000000) > 22.000000) THEN GETDATE()
```

You cannot do compound comparison operations in SQL like you can in many languages. These need to be broken out into individual operations combined with the logical operator `AND`.

```
CASE
  WHEN StandardUnitCost < AverageUnitCost THEN GETDATE()
  WHEN (AverageUnitCost + 2.0) > 22 
     AND  StandardUnitCost > (AverageUnitCost + 2.0) THEN GETDATE()
  WHEN StandardUnitCost < 22.0 THEN GETDATE()
  ELSE DateUpdated
END
```

But what about when [StandardUnitCost] = 22.0? Currently if StandardUnitCost is not "<" AverageUnitCost (the first condition), then this logic is only checking for > 22.000002 (or something like that) and < 22.0. It just seems like at least one of those comparisons needs to be either `<=` or `>=`.

Comment: That is a good question, and thank you for the help here! I'm still new to SQL, and I am playing around on a test server. At first I was trying to make a way to define fields that had been changed by the second case formula, but that is quite ahead of me. I was thinking maybe a variable? Doing that would eliminate the need for the first case statement all together. What would be the preferred method of going about something like that, is it a variable like I am thinking, or something completely different?

Comment: @Xestius Well, you first need to be clearer about your overall goal. Maybe start by describing what you are trying to accomplish, where the posted code was an attempt to accomplish it rather than the goal being to get this code working. I am not exactly sure what you mean by "make a way to define fields that had been changed by the second case formula". Do you mean that the 2nd formula is the real task, and you want an indication of which rows are changing vs falling through to the ELSE?

Comment: My overall goal is to update the pricing model only on parts that need to be updated while also updated the Dateupdated field only on those same lines. I am using a tool that syncs the data by matching up to the Dateupdated column only, so it is important that it only changes on lines that the Standardunitcost has also updated on. It is important that both happen, and only on the same rows.

Comment: @Xestius Ok, that is much better. How about posting that text with the 2nd UPDATE statement in a new question and I can show you how to do that in a single statement. And post a link to that question here, please :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27362612/i-would-like-to-merge-both-of-these-update-statements-into-one
Here is that link you asked for. Also, as far as the website goes, when I try to reply to you using @ then your name, it just disappears. Is that normal?

Comment: @Xestius The person who posts the question or answer doesn't need to be specified via "@" syntax as they are already notified of comments on something they post. But since you didn't post this answer, I need to use the "@" to notify you.