# T-SQL How to set modification date without Trigger only if other values actually changed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My overall goal is to update the [StandardUnitCost] field only on "parts" that need to be updated while also updating the [DateUpdated] field only on those same lines. I am using a tool that syncs the data by matching up to the [DateUpdated] column only, so it is important that it only changes on lines that the [StandardUnitCost] has also updated on. It is important that both happen, and only on the same rows. If the [StandardUnitCost] field will be updated with the same value that it currently has, then the value has not changed and the [DateUpdated] field should *not* be updated.

I currently have this as two separate update statements and need help combining them.

```
Update [mas_wgd].[dbo].[CI_Item]
  Set dateupdated = CASE
   WHEN StandardUnitCost < AverageUnitCost then convert (date, GETDATE())
   WHEN (AverageUnitCost + 2) >= 22.0
    AND standardunitcost > (AverageUnitCost + 2.000000) then convert (date, GETDATE())
   When StandardUnitCost < 22.000000
    And StandardUnitCost > 0 then convert (date, GETDATE())
  Else dateupdated
end
Where ProductLine IN ('A010', 'A020', 'A030', 'A040', 'A050', 'A060', 'A070', 'A080',
      'A090', 'A100', 'A110', 'A120', 'A130', 'A130', 'A140', 'A150', 'A200', 'A250',
      'A300', 'A350', 'A400', 'A450', 'A500', 'A550', 'A600', 'AGNC', 'C010', 'C020',
      'C030', 'C040', 'C050', 'C060', 'C070', 'C080', 'C090', 'C100', 'C110', 'C120',
      'C130', 'C130', 'C140', 'C150', 'C200', 'C250', 'C300', 'C350', 'C400', 'C450',
      'C500', 'C550', 'C600', 'CGNC')


Update [mas_wgd].[dbo].[CI_Item]
 Set Standardunitcost = CASE
  WHEN (AverageUnitCost between 0.010000 and 22.000000) Then  22.00000 
  WHEN AverageUnitCost > 22.000000 then AverageUnitCost + 2.000000
 Else StandardUnitCost 
end
Where ProductLine IN ('A010', 'A020', 'A030', 'A040', 'A050', 'A060', 'A070', 'A080',
      'A090', 'A100', 'A110', 'A120', 'A130', 'A130', 'A140', 'A150', 'A200', 'A250',
      'A300', 'A350', 'A400', 'A450', 'A500', 'A550', 'A600', 'AGNC', 'C010', 'C020',
      'C030', 'C040', 'C050', 'C060', 'C070', 'C080', 'C090', 'C100', 'C110', 'C120',
      'C130', 'C130', 'C140', 'C150', 'C200', 'C250', 'C300', 'C350', 'C400', 'C450',
      'C500', 'C550', 'C600', 'CGNC')
```

Comment: Can you not just add the second column to update in the first update statement?

Comment: If you have the same `Where` statements (2nd has no end in example) you could write it in on `Update` using comma.

Comment: @SeanLange I have no clue.I was thinking it could possibly be a reactionary thing? Like because one line changes, then the other on changes as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this via a CTE will allow you to specify the formula once and use it to trigger the update on both fields:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;

DECLARE @Test TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
                     AverageUnitCost INT NULL,
                     StandardUnitCost INT NULL,
                     ModifiedDate DATETIME,
                     WasUpdated BIT NULL);
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (5, 8, GETDATE(), 0);
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (15, 11, GETDATE(), 0);
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (12, 35, GETDATE(), 0);
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (22, 47, GETDATE(), 0);

SELECT * FROM @Test;

;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT tmp.ID,
         tmp.StandardUnitCost,
         tmp.ModifiedDate,
         tmp.WasUpdated,
         CASE WHEN tmp.AverageUnitCost BETWEEN 10 AND 20 THEN 22
              WHEN tmp.AverageUnitCost > 20 THEN (tmp.AverageUnitCost + 2)
              ELSE tmp.StandardUnitCost
         END AS [NewValue]
  FROM @Test tmp
  --WHERE ProductLine IN ('A010'...) -- this is part of the real table so uncomment
)
UPDATE tab
SET    tab.StandardUnitCost = tab.NewValue,
       tab.ModifiedDate = GETDATE(),
       tab.WasUpdated = 1 -- only here to clearly indicate that the row was updated
FROM   cte tab
WHERE  tab.StandardUnitCost <> tab.NewValue;

SELECT * FROM @Test;
```

The [WasUpdated] field is only there because the statement runs fast enough where there might not be a difference in value for the [ModifiedDate] field on rows that were updated.

Comment: This is simply exceeding my knowledge of SQL. Do you possibly have some reading material to recommend to start catching me up to this level? The only thing I have currently is the "Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012" book.

Comment: @Xestius Here is one resource http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/ . You need to register to read the articles but it's free.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at it, and read up on everything I can.

Comment: @Xestius I noticed your comment on the other answer. I had a feeling something was off earlier but didn't see it. The issue is that the formula is defined on the field in that way of doing it. In order to make it work you would have to duplicate that logic in the WHERE clause, and at that point you haven't really simplified anything. That is why I felt this way was simpler: the logic is defined once. A CTE is an inline View.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can simplify your query by moving the criteria for `StandardCost` updating to the `WHERE` clause, in which case you will be guaranteed that the matching rows will be updated and hence can also confidently timestamp the `dateupdated` column at the same time:

```
Update [mas_wgd].[dbo].[CI_Item]
  Set dateupdated = convert (date, GETDATE()),
  Standardunitcost = 
    CASE
       WHEN (AverageUnitCost between 0.010000 and 22.000000) Then  22.00000 
       WHEN AverageUnitCost > 22.000000 then AverageUnitCost + 2.000000
    END -- CASE
Where ProductLine IN ('A010', ...  'CGNC')
AND  (AverageUnitCost > 0.010000);
```

It appears that the common theme between the `CASE` update on `StandardUnitCost` is that it will be updated any time that `AverageUnitCost` is greater than `0.010000`.

This will also avoid redundant updates of the form `Set dateupdated = dateupdated` and `Standardunitcost = Standardunitcost`

Comment: Ok, This is very simple compared to the wall of text I had. I do have a question however. Wouldn't the `end` stop everything abouve it from interacting with `AND (AverageUnitCost > 0.010000)`?

Comment: The end terminates the CASE? I've improved the indentation - hopefully more clear?

Comment: Ah, alright. That does make more sense now. Thank you.

Comment: After toying around and using this query, I noticed that it does not have to update the prices in order to update the dates, which is what I way trying to avoid. This works nicely except for that. If i go in and change the dates, but all of the pricing information is correctly entered into the system, the dates are still changing. I think I might have to read into SQL and bit more, and try what @srutzky mentioned to try out below. Thanks!

Comment: I see - if the `Standardunitcost` is already the exact same value and a redundant update happens, you don't want the date to change? Then `srutzky`'s idea with a CTE / derived table to DRY up the 'look ahead' is a good one. A Sql trigger could also be used (`inserted.Standardunitcost <> Standardunitcost`, albeit messy.

Comment: @Xestius and Stuart, I had added a comment a moment ago thinking that putting the "does not equal current value of StandardUnitCost" condition into each of the WHEN clauses would help, but then I realized it wouldn't and removed the comment. The logic really does need to be duplicated in the WHERE as well. And yes, I agree with Stuart that while a Trigger would work, it is messier than required here.